# Perl opening dynamically generated files

Tags: perl, file-io, backticks

I am using CGI script for my website. And I have problem with opening a dynamically generated file. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @output = `/export/es_share/Zhou/./notification_finder.sh range $date $time $range $ulh TestProd1 $actionname`;
my $filen = $output[0];
open(my $result, "<", $filen) or die "Can't open $filen - $!";
Do something with the file...
```

Always fails, with the output:

```
Can't open /var/tmp/notification-finder-1375086676-658183725.tmp - 
No such file or directory at /var/www/cgi-bin/appsupport/logapp_test/perltest.cgi line X.
```

While as this succeeds:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(my $result, "<", /var/tmp/notification-finder-1375086676-658183725.tmp) or die "Can't open $filen - $!";
Do something with the file...
```

I have also checked if it was the problem of asynchronous execution of the backticks problem, but from my research on stackoverflow it does not seem to be the issue. I also tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @output = `/export/es_share/Zhou/./notification_finder.sh range $date $time $range $ulh TestProd1 $actionname`;
sleep(10);
my $filen = $output[0];
open(my $result, "<", $filen) or die "Can't open $filen - $!";
Do something with the file...
```

I have found this [similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798111/issue-with-filepath-name-possible-corrupt-characters), but I don't seem to have the same problem as the asker... Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: Perhaps you can use something like [`File::Temp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ATemp).

Comment: @TLP could ou please elaborate a bit more? I am new to Perl. :)

Comment: No, I'm afraid I've never used that module. I'm not sure you can use it in this context, of passing a temp file name to a system command.

Comment: @TLP I will read on the link, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates there is a newline on the end of `$filen`, otherwise it would be:

```
Can't open /var/tmp/notification-finder-1375086676-658183725.tmp - No such file or directory at /var/www/cgi-bin/appsupport/logapp_test/perltest.cgi line XXXXXXXXX.
```

Remove it with:

```
chomp $filen;
```

Comment: Simply GREAT diagnostics!